# How does the 2D Fourier Transform operate on Partial Derivates?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, multiple-integral

In my class, the professor gave us the following definitions for the $2$D Fourier Transform :
$$ \hat{u}(k,\omega)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i(kx-\omega t)}\ u(x,t)\ dx \ dt $$
$$ u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i(kx-\omega t)}\ \hat{u}(k,\omega)\ dk \ d\omega $$

I want to know what the $2$D Fourier Transform does to partial derivatives and I don't feel as confident in my derivations because of the implications of dealing with double integrals. For example, say I want to find what the $2$D Fourier Transform does to a time derivative $v_t(x,t)$ then by definition I would have:
$$ \hat{v}_t(k,\omega)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i(kx-\omega t)}\ v_t(x,t) \ dx \ dt $$
Just looking at this double integral, my first thought is to switch the order of integration and try to use integration by parts to turn $v_t$ into $v$; however, I am not sure if my function obeys Fubini's Theorem or not. And further, I'm not quite sure how integration by parts would work in this case if it is allowed. Also, I feel I may be well overthinking this. In class, my professor - in one line - would simply start with a PDE such as
$$ u_{tt}+\gamma^2u_{xxxx}=0 $$
and then write "take $2$D Fourier Transform" so we have:
$$ p(k,\omega)\hat{u}(k,\omega)=0 $$
where
$$ p(k,\omega) = \omega^2-\gamma^2k^4=0 $$

This seems to suggest to me that the $2$D Fourier Transform turns partial derivatives with respect to time into a multiplication by $i\omega$ and partial derivatives with respect to space ($x$) into a multiplication by $ik$. I think I should be able to derive these rules from the definition but am stuck on how to treat this double integral.

Any help/hints/advice is much appreciated! Or a reference to any website or paper that goes through these types of derivations would also be incredible.

EDIT: This is my attempt at taking the $2$D Fourier Transform of $v_t$:
$$ \hat{v}_t(k,\omega)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i(kx-\omega t)}\ v_t(x,t) \ dx \ dt $$
$$ = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ikx}[\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\omega t}v_t(x,t) dt] dx $$
Applying integration by parts on the inner integral and letting the surface term vanish we have:
$$ = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}(-i\omega)e^{-ikx}e^{i\omega t}v(x,t) dt dx $$
And by definition this implies that we have:
$$ =(-i\omega)\hat{u}(k,\omega) $$
My concern is that I'm not quite sure why we would require the surface term to vanish. Would it generally be a condition that $u \rightarrow 0$ as $|t|\rightarrow\infty$? If so why? Would we also require $u \rightarrow 0$ as $|x|\rightarrow\infty$ for the derivation of the $2$D Fourier Transform of the spatial partial derivative $u_x$? If so can someone explain why we require these conditions?

Comment: Not the time to write a full answer but: Yes, in general, in most PDE, solutions are $0$ at $\infty$. Usually uniqueness of PDE is proved in Sobolev spaces. And indeed, even for the heat equation, there can be crazy solutions if you look at spaces with functions growing fast at infinity. But, PDE are about physical systems for which we do not want to have infinitely many crazy solutions but we prefer looking to the good space where the solution is unique

Comment: Another last thing also, is that to define the Fourier transform of singular functions, one uses distribution theory. There, everything is defined by duality with the set of smooth functions decaying fast at infinity.

Comment: Is my computation of the integral correct? i.e. is it true that $ \hat{u}_t(k,\omega)=(-i\omega)\hat{u}(k,\omega) $

Comment: Is it also true that: $ \hat{u}_x(k,\omega) = (-ik)\hat{u}(k,\omega) $

Comment: Thanks for addressing my other concerns!